# Missing movies attribute on result Vue GraphQL

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I am frontend developer so for the first time I got my hands on vue and graphql, I don’t know how exactly to deal with this error:

```
Missing getMovies attribute on result {movies: Array(20)}
```

Here is my code, and I can see the data is fetched successfully in the response on dev tools in chrome:

```
{"data":{"movies":[{"__typename":"Movie","id":11,"overview":
```

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id">{{movie.title}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data(){
    return {
      movies: []
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    getMovies: {
      query: gql`
        query StarWars {
          movies(query: "Star Wars") {
            title
            overview
            poster_path
            id
          }
        }      
      `,
      result({data}){
        this.movies = data.movies
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo/issues/10), your `apollo` property should have a matching `data` property, but in this case they are mismatched (one is named `movies` and `getMovies`). Change one or the other:

```
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data(){
    return {
      movies: []
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    movies: {
      query: gql`
        query StarWars {
          movies(query: "Star Wars") {
            title
            overview
            poster_path
            id
          }
        }      
      `
    }
  },
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
```

Setting the `data` yourself inside `result` isn't necessary.